# Multiple Office 365 logon prompt box while running automated script

Tags: powershell, office365

I am in the process of automating a piece of our user creation. I am trying to automate an email notification. When I pull the list of names from the CSV through PowerShell, It prompts every time for the username and password, even though I have it in the code. Is there a way around this? Code below.

````
$FromEmail = ""
$SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$Port = 587
$Password = ""
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
# Create Credential Object
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($FromEmail, $SecurePassword)

foreach($row in $CsvData)
{
   $ToEmail = "$($row."Manager Email")"
   $Subject = "New User Created"
   $Body = "<html><body>
      <h2>Attention $($row.Manager),</h2>
      <div>The following user has been created in the IT systems.&nbsp;</div>
      <div>User: $($row."EE FIRST NAME") $($row."EE LAST NAME")</div>
      <div>Title: $($row."Title")</div>
      <div>Employee ID: $($row."EE ID")</div>
      <div>Email: $($row."Email")</div>
      <p>useful info</p>
      <p>some more useful info</p>
      <p>Thank you,</p>
      <p>IT</p>"

  [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'TLS12'
  Send-MailMessage -From $FromEmail -To $ToEmail -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -UseSsl -Port $Port -Credential $Credential -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml
} ```
````

Comment: Your credential variable is `$Credentials` yet, you use `-Credential $Credential` :) you also want to remove the parenthesis from `New-Object ....`

Comment: Wow, Thank you i have been staring at this for days wondering where I messed up and it was a spelling error.  thank you.

Comment: Of course, my pleasure :) It's also worth noting, if `$Password` is a encrypted string this will __only work__ with the user that encrypted the string and from the computer where it was encrypted.

Comment: Yes thank you!!